# Cannot get value from list group item for ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've tried many solutions but I still cannot get this value to be sent via an ajax request. Below the user can click on a link in the side navbar and I want the category name to be sent to the controller.

```
    <div class="mini-submenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
        <span href="#" class="list-group-item active">
            Categories
            <span class="pull-right" id="slide-submenu">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
        <% Movie.category_types.keys.each do |category| %>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> <%= category.capitalize.humanize %> <span class="badge"><%= Movie.find_category_amount(category) %></span>
            </a>
        <% end %>
    </div>  
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $(".list-group-item").on('click',function(e) { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: $(this).attr('value'),
                url: "<%= movies_path %>",
                dataType : "script",
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the category name by

```
e.target.childNodes[1].data // to send only the category name, OR
e.target.innerText // to send the full text inside the dom element
```

Also, use `preventDefault()`. So, for example:

```
$(".list-group-item").on('click',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: {category_name: e.target.childNodes[1].data},
      url: "/your_path_here",
      dataType : "script"
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. The strange thing is no data is being passed in the params. I can't even see the key category_name.

Comment: If you do a `console.log(e)` on click, does it log the event?

Comment: `dataType:'script'` seems unusual for a use case like this

Comment: And if you try `dataType:'json'` ? Like charlieftl mentions

Comment: No still the same. The strange thing is if I replace the data with '{ 'example': 'test '}', it works, I can see it in the params.